# How to store global statuses and/or parameters of an iOS app with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I've written a little application with different `UIViewController`s. In my AppDelegate I've this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                 initWithRootViewController:
                                 [[MainViewController alloc] init]];
```

MainViewController, contains a method:

```
- (void)aMethod
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[CellViewController alloc] init]             
                                         animated:TRUE];
}
```

CellViewController, contains a method:

```
- (void)aMethod
{
    StartToBuildViewController * controller = [[StartToBuildViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:true];
}
```

And so on. My question is: What's the best way to share informations from a `UIViewController` to others? I just need to store flag status and/or datetime value. Can I use global variables? Database? What else?

I came from php, and in php I would use database or session variables.

Comment: What kind of status? What kind of date? Are you asking about how to persist the values or about how to share them between classes while your app is running?

Comment: The first one: how to persist values while my app is running.

Comment: OK. What kind of status? What kind of date?

Comment: I've solved using @property in AppDelegate singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IOS SDK, its depend on user requirement and understanding.
While you can store flags in NSUserDefault or Create Global variable using extern or create AppDelegate variable with define property.

thanks

Comment: There arent user requirement, I just whant to understand what Objective-C offers.

Comment: IOS Offer different kind on flag/variable strorage. In IOS, you can store information in SQlite DB, NSuserdefault or in global variable. its totally depend on developer and type on information.